# How to access Azure Linux web app path file

Tags: linux, file, asp.net-core, azure-webapps

Trying to access file on path - wwwroot/templates/file.txt. It works using -_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "\templates\file.txt" on windows but same path says file does not exists.
What Am I missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trying to access file on path - wwwroot/templates/file.txt.

The following code snippet work for me, you can refer to it.

```
var filepath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "templates", "file.txt");

var mes = "test message";

if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
{
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filepath))
    {
        mes = file.ReadLine();
    }
}

ViewBag.fp = filepath;

ViewBag.mes = mes;

return View();
```

And please make sure the file is really existing under that folder on your server.

[image]

Test Result

[image]